# How to look inside .ktx textures?

Tags: c++, file, textures

I want to look into .ktx textures. What I mean by that is to get a texture, open it by some text editor and just watch what is inside it. That's of course a very basic example, I guess I need a bit more than just open text editor.

What I know right now, is how to read texture's data and send it to a GPU.

```cpp
struct Header
{
    unsigned char identifier[12];
    unsigned int endianness;
    unsigned int gltype;
    unsigned int gltypesize;
    unsigned int glformat;
    unsigned int glinternalformat;
    unsigned int glbaseinternalformat;
    unsigned int pixelwidth;
    unsigned int pixelheight;
    unsigned int pixeldepth;
    unsigned int arrayelements;
    unsigned int faces;
    unsigned int miplevels;
    unsigned int keypairbytes;
};


static const unsigned char identifier[] =
{
    0xAB, 0x4B, 0x54, 0x58, 0x20, 0x31, 0x31, 0xBB, 0x0D, 0x0A, 0x1A, 0x0A
};

static const unsigned int swap32(const unsigned int u32)
{
    union
    {
        unsigned int u32;
        unsigned char u8[4];
    } a, b;

    a.u32 = u32;
    b.u8[0] = a.u8[3];
    b.u8[1] = a.u8[2];
    b.u8[2] = a.u8[1];
    b.u8[3] = a.u8[0];

    return b.u32;
}

unsigned char* LoadKTX(const std::string& filePath)
{
    FILE* file = nullptr;
    fopen_s(&file, filePath.c_str(), "rb");
    if (!file) { return nullptr; }

    Header header;

    fread_s(&header, sizeof(header), sizeof(header), 1, file);

    if (memcmp(header.identifier, identifier, sizeof(identifier)) != 0) {
        std::cout << "Bad identifier\n";
    }

    if (header.endianness == 0x04030201) {
        // Zamiana nie jest konieczna.
    } else if (header.endianness == 0x01020304) {
        // Konieczna zamiana
        header.endianness = swap32(header.endianness);
        header.gltype = swap32(header.gltype);
        header.gltypesize = swap32(header.gltypesize);
        header.glformat = swap32(header.glformat);
        header.glinternalformat = swap32(header.glinternalformat);
        header.glbaseinternalformat = swap32(header.glbaseinternalformat);
        header.pixelwidth = swap32(header.pixelwidth);
        header.pixelheight = swap32(header.pixelheight);
        header.pixeldepth = swap32(header.pixeldepth);
        header.arrayelements = swap32(header.arrayelements);
        header.faces = swap32(header.faces);
        header.miplevels = swap32(header.miplevels);
        header.keypairbytes = swap32(header.keypairbytes);
    }

    size_t startData = ftell(file) + header.keypairbytes;
    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);
    size_t endData = ftell(file);
    fseek(file, startData, SEEK_SET);

    unsigned char* data = new unsigned char[endData - startData];
    std::memset(data, 0, endData - startData);
    fread_s(data, endData - startData, 1, endData - startData, file);

    return data;
}
```

Data that is returned by `LoadKTX()` function is ready to go to the GPU.

How can I convert this code to be able to read each pixel, each line of the texture?

Comment: You might be able to read simple RGBA data directly but, IIRC, ktx also supports compressed formats such as ETC, PVRTC...  For those you will need the decompression functions.  PVRTC decode there is (or used to be) source code in the PowerVR SDK. Similarly, I believe Ericsson released decompression code for ETC.

Comment: How to know what compression format is it?

Comment: Judging from https://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/tools/KTX/file_format_spec/#2.6  it's the glinternalformat field that determines this.